# P-early-media header in 183 Session Progress messages

Tags: sip

I'm analyzing a problem with a SIP call where the caller is not receiving the ring back tone. In the trace I see the INVITE message with SDP sent by the caller PBX and the 183 Session Progress with SDP received by the caller PBX without the P-early-media header (unfortunately I cannot trace the called device behavior).

No other messages are received by the caller PBX.

The caller doesn't hear anything (the ringback tone isn't generate by any device) and after a while the call is cancelled by the caller PBX.

The question is: in this scenario who must generate the ringback tone?

The absence of the p-early-media in the 183 session progress received by the caller PBX could mean that the called PBX hasn't inserted it or that a SIP proxy deleted it because early media is not permitted in that network.

In any case, must the caller PBX generate the ring back tone because the p-early-media header is not present in the received 183 session progress message?

Answer (score 0):

In that case the calling device must not generate a local ringback tone but instead switch the audio flow received in the 183 answer.
Btw, it is probably not a ringback tone but an informative message that is actually played out like "The number is not available"; acording to the received SIP messages where not 180 is received at all it is not guaranted that a called device is ringing.

About P-early-media, it is rather specific to 3GPP SIP networks, I am not sure if it is of other use.